# upper bound of sequence of functions

Tags: calculus, limits

What function will be an upper bound of the sequence
$f_{n}(x)=\Bigl(1-\frac{x}{n}\Bigr)^{n}\ln(x)$

since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(1-\frac{x}{n}\Bigr)^{n}=e^{-x}$ so we should probably bound above by the exponential function.

Someone knows how to do that?

Comment: It should be $\ln(x)e^{-x}$.

Comment: does this also hold for $x>0$???

Answer (score 1):

$f_{n}(x)\leq e^{-x}\ln{x}$ for all $n$. You already know that 
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-\tfrac{x}{n})^{n}=e^{-x}$. For any $n$ and $x$, $(1-\tfrac{x}{n})^{n}\leq e^{-x}$ so you are done.

Comment: I was just wondering if this really works: If we take e.q $x=10$ and $n=2$ then $(1-5)^2\ln(2)\approx 9.7>0.0000314\approx e^{-10}\ln(2)$

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\left(1 - \frac {x} {n}\right)^n < e^{-x}$$ for $n \geqslant 1$, we obtain $f_n (x) < e^{-x} \log x$. We also have, as $n \to +\infty$, that $$f_n (x) \to e^{-x} \log x.$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove that

$$ f_{n}(x)=\Bigl(1-\frac{x}{n}\Bigr)^{n} $$

is an increasing bounded above sequence in order to use $e^{-x}$ as an upper bound for the sequence.